# ajax don't work on iphone anymore

Tags: php, iphone, ajax

I use a form to insert data into a mysql database using php and ajax.
it has always worked both on the desktop and mobile.

Now, when inserting data, **ONLY FROM IPHONE** (tested on iphone 6s and iphone x, both from Safari and from Chrome) the procedure does not work and reports a 400 or 0 error.

**From desktops and devices Not apple works everything.**

this is the code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH_AJAX', 'true');
            }
        });
</script>       
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        $('#ShowData').html('<img src="img/loader.gif" height="16" width="16"/>');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ins_ok.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data, status)
            { 
                $('#ShowData').html(data);
                $('#Ins')[0].reset();
                $('#Data').datepicker('update', '');

            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err)
            {
                alert('Dati al momento non disponibili. Riprovare più tardi.'); 
                console.warn(xhr.responseText);
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(err);
            }
        });        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't much information here. The best way to test it would be to do some logging on the server side to see if it's getting to the script and where it's breaking. Also hook the iPhone up to a computer and use the debugging tools. Both Safari and Chrome can debug their respective counterparts on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

With the new iOS 11 update there's an issue with the formData() object. I had the same issue when trying to submit a form with the option to have an image and if the user doesn't include an image it fails.

Now, I guess, when iOS is using the formData() object if the image input value is empty it just tries to send an empty object, which is illegal with JSON. I ended up creating a nasty function that says:

```
if (image input is null) {
    disable the image input;
}
```

And then after the callback was completed I had to "re enable" the image input feature again. I searched for hours for a solution, but it's really new because iOS 11 is so new.

Here's a reference to this question that helped me solve it:
[My $.ajax request stopped working properly on iOS 11.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578686/my-ajax-request-stopped-working-properly-on-ios-11-3)